# Call VarFormat (Windows API) from Python

Tags: python, ctypes, pywin32, win32com

I'm currently converting some C code to Python and I've hit a sticking point with calling `VarFormat`. For most of the other API interactions I've been able to find existing `pywin32` examples or pure Python implementations. My own knowledge of how to work with the Windows API like this is limited though.

I know that I can import `VARIANT` from `win32com.client` and I can get access to `VarFormat` via `ctypes.oledll.oleaut32.VarFormat`.

The attempt I made was

```
from win32com.client import VARIANT
import ctypes

VarFormat = ctypes.oledll.oleaut32.VarFormat

value = '84'        # value used for demonstration
format_str = '00'   # value used for demonstration

v = VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_I4, int(value))    # hardcoded to int for demonstration
output_str = ''
result = VarFormat(ctypes.addressof(v), format_str, 0, 0, 0, ctypes.addressof(output_str))
```

but I get

```
TypeError: invalid type
```

If I use `byref` instead of `addressof` then I get

```
TypeError: byref() argument must be a ctypes instance, not 'VARIANT'
```

which implies to me that I can't directly mix things from the two packages like that, though I was under the impression that `pywin32` used `ctypes` underneath.

Could someone point me in the right direction with this?

I'm also happy to hear about replacements for `VarFormat` that won't require a trip out to the Windows API, as the `VARIANT` is mostly just created for convenience for this one call in the original code.

Comment: You would probably have to derive the whole `VARIANT` structure from a `ctypes.Structure`.

Comment: *PyWin32* and *CTypes* inner types (classes) are generally not compatible. *PyWin23* uses *CTypes* for a small subset of its features.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Looks like I have some learning to do :)